# HiveServer: ClassNotFound (HiveServer)

Tags: hadoop, hive

first of all: I am new to Hive.

I just installed Hive and when I run "hive" the server starts up and brings me into the CLI. But when I try to start it as a service/server with "hive --service hiveserver" I get:

> Starting Hive Thrift Server
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Two questions:

1. Is that the right way to start up a Hive server? (My understanding is that HCat and WebHCat are included automatically!?)
2. Why does this problem show up and how can I resolve it?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: what version of hive are you using?

Comment: It's the latest version - so 1.0.0

Comment: try 'hive --service hiveserver2'

Answer (score 6):

Try to run `bin/hive --service hiveserver2` instead of `hive --service hiveserver` for this version of apache hive

Comment: Hi @HMS **"hive --service hiveserver2"** worked but it does not print any log.Does it print any logs?

Comment: You have to change hive-log4j.properties.template.

Comment: how to change the hive-log4j.properties.template. can you please mention the command

Comment: change for what ? if you want to use hive-log4j.properties.template then simply rename it to  hive-log4j.properties